# What is Heroku PG:PULL back-end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, pg

How to reproduce

```
heroku pg:pull
```

in my own environment.
(Clone production db to local)

Is it possible to clone db from production to local machine if production configured to use AWS as database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe
    mysqldump -u root -h heroku_database_host -p  heroku_database_name - > backup.sql

Comment: this is not exact functional)
You are right, this will work for dump DB into sql file, and later I can import it into local DB, but magic of heroku pg:pull made everythin in one command.

Comment: no no no, this is documentation about Heroku, I know how it works. I just wonder how to reproduce the same by myself, without heroku.